# Angular App Module issue with: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mean-stack

I am having issues with the following line of code:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Now, I have created a web application running on a localhost. It is being built in Mac OSX. I am also using: Angular 6, Angular Material, and JavaScript. I want to integrate a sidenav component using the following website: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ovxopareljk?file=main.ts. I have tried pasting in the exact same code and even updated each dependency but the code still does not work. I have deduced that the issue lies in the line of code above. The image attached displays the exact error and the code: [Click this link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0huVw.jpg). Any help to resolve the error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It needs importing `import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';`

Comment: this worked, thank you.